# MSSql Query Issue

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables

```
-Projects(ProjectId[PK], Status ...)
-UserProjects(UserProectId[PK], ProectId[FK], UserId[FK], ...)
-Users(UserId[PK], ...)
```

I want choose projects with status = 1 and project must be project which user is not involved.

Here is what I`ve tried:

```
Select UP.ProjectId from UserProjects UP
Join Projects P on UP.ProjectId = P.ProjectId
Where P.Status = 1 AND UP.UserId != 1
```

[image]

Result which I want should be just 16. It gives me also 17 because User 1 and User 3 are in Project 17.

Anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grouping with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT UP.ProjectId 
FROM UserProjects UP
INNER JOIN Projects P ON UP.ProjectId = P.ProjectId
WHERE P.Status = 1 
GROUP BY  UP.ProjectId 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN UP.UserId = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The `HAVING` clause filters out projects related to user with `UserId = 1`.

Alternatively you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ProjectId
FROM Projects AS P
WHERE Status = 1 AND 
      NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM UserProjects AS UP
                 WHERE UP.ProjectId = P.ProjectId AND UP.UserId = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I am trying to rewrite it to LINQ but without success can You help me with this also ?:)

Comment: @miechooy That's a different question. Try writing a new post here is SO!